# Calling a method in play WebSocket in Scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka

I am new to scala, Play framework and Akka. I have function defined as

```
def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MyWebSocketActor.props(out))
  }
```

This i want to call from other class .I am not clear how to call this function as, i can't call this by

```
objectName.socket(implict req:RequestHeader)
```

I am working in Play 2.5.3 , Scala 2.11.7 and Akka 2.4.7 .

**Edit:** it gives me error : `'=>' expected, ')' found`

Comment: Why would you want to call that method? It is supposed to go into the routes file of your application.

Comment: I want to make it as an api, so that i can call it from other new project to accept connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure, what the benefit of that would be, but I'll try to answer your question.

First of all, this (`objectName.socket(implict req:RequestHeader)`) ist not how you call a method with an implicit parameter (also you have a typo there in implicit).

But as you already pointed out correctly, you need an implicit `RequestHeader`, so you only can call this method within the context of a `Controller`.

def anotherControllerAction = objectName.socket

That would basically just point `anotherControllerAction` to the socket implementation. Then you still need to put `anotherControllerAction` into your routes file.

**You might want to describe in more detail, what you actually want to achieve**